# Omitting a shared property from a union type of objects results in error when using non-shared properties (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am creating a wrapper function that passes a `refs` property into a `send` function as seen below. The Event type used to create my state machine is defined as an intersection between a base interface `{ refs: NodeRefs }` and a union of possible event objects, e.g. `{ type: "EVENT_1" } | { type: "EVENT_2", context: MyContextType }`.

The wrapper function (`useMachine` in the example code) should return our updated `send` function that expects an event object where the `refs` key is omitted. Using `Omit` here then results in an error when trying to use my send function with any non-shared properties from the union type and I'm not 100% clear why or how to do it differently.

```
enum States {
  Unchecked = "UNCHECKED",
  Checked = "CHECKED",
  Mixed = "MIXED"
}

enum Events {
  Toggle = "TOGGLE",
  Set = "SET",
  UpdateContext = "UPDATE_CONTEXT"
}

// Events for the state machine will be a union type a la TEvent, but all events
// will need a `refs` property. We just won't need to explicitly pass refs in
// our event calls thanks to the useMachine hook below
interface EventBase {
  refs: NodeRefs;
}

type TEvent = EventBase &
  (
    | { type: Events.Toggle }
    | {
        type: Events.Set;
        state: States;
      }
    | {
        type: Events.UpdateContext;
        context: Partial<Context>;
      }
  );

function useMachine(stateMachine: SomeStateMachine, refs: ReactRefs) {
  let [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState(stateMachine.initialState);
  /* ... */
  // I want to omit the refs property from our event here because we are always
  // sending the same values in each event, but this is triggering the error
  // in our send function below.
  function send(event: Omit<TEvent, "refs">) {
    let nodes = Object.keys(refs).reduce(nodeReducer);
    service.send({ ...event, refs: nodes });
  }
  return [currentState, send];
}

function MyComponent({ disabled }) {
  let inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  let [currentState, send] = useMachine(myStateMachine, { input: inputRef });

  useEffect(() => {
    send({
      type: Events.UpdateContext,
      // Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'context'
      // does not exist in type 'Pick<TEvent, "type">'.
      context: { disabled }
    });
  }, [disabled]);
  /* ... */
}

type NodeRefs = {
  input: HTMLInputElement | null;
};

type ReactRefs = {
  [K in keyof NodeRefs]: React.RefObject<NodeRefs[K]>;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your issue is likely caused by the fact that the built in utility type [`Omit<T, K>`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk), like [`Pick<T, K>`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk), does not [distribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) over unions in `T`.  You seem to expect (which is not unreasonable), that `Omit<A | B, K>` should be equivalent to `Omit<A, K> | Omit<B, K>`, but it doesn't work that way.  Instead, `Omit<A | B, K>` maps over `keyof (A | B)`, which is the same as `(keyof A) & (keyof B)` and you find yourself only seeing shared properties.

The easiest fix for this is to create a version of `Omit` that *does* distribute over unions by employing a [distributive conditional type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  If you have a generic type parameter `T`, then the construct `T extends any ? F<T> : never` will end up distributing the `F<>` operation over `T` when `T` is a union type. Here's the definition:

```
type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends any ? Omit<T, K> : never;
```

You can verify that `DistributiveOmit<A | B, K>` will now be exactly equivalent to `DistributiveOmit<A, K> | Distributive<B, K>`.  And thus `DistributiveOmit<TEvent, "refs">` will be a union itself:

```
function foo(event: DistributiveOmit<TEvent, "refs">) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case Events.Set: {
      event.state; // okay
      break;
    }
    case Events.Toggle: {
      break;
    }
    case Events.UpdateContext: {
      event.context; // okay
    }
  }
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BAHsKBeKBvKBjALigGdgAnASwQHMoBfAbigHpmoB3ACzigGsE47YgFgAUGIgIArgFsoAZWABDZMRxioUAKoI8nCHl4QAJpigAiLQDkYACQCiMANL2AIuYA0G2PsMmz5naOLu5eopoAshQo-ljmEQCSABpu5mJ0YhLScvYAbpLAatjeACpw1NQANtBxJQDyAOINADL2nt7yEOhx8vYl7eHaYMYqEPBIqN0WWgAKrgCCJfYA+jB1VktJ-emZoqCQUFZwxhAAShAAZmpYuEpEpJQ09AxiVMhkF0p40HkFAEJKYjQYqDMiXYhEI4nc5XF6iDLhMT7aBLfJIMy-JAAoFQABk3gAFN5NAAfHBQZFETGFAB0ZQq1XoxKgZJBmnZFPAECpaNpnWAcI5mlIoyIilGxEF7IRHNZzM0lKg1OINK0w1G42QaClHLwiC1wCIMyUZGAFCUlQAPJrJgA+HVMwYASjhSK5UFcFAeFAARlIzfk6jIKMBLSUPFAnFBJpJjGoZmQ4JBTSAnBAQLazCVo2hY2olAgQFAAPxQIMhsMRpyZogICD5Miu0QXKS6M2IKAXOBwAn1gpET3ev0BiDl0OogoR8xgq7mW1O9SDYjsEN6KC93k05ELtnsvCAn68lX8oi7jl9pA0kXIJisKBwXhKEDyqA+sFKXgOmV7g9Ko908oqm5RchVfd9P2Zb9NH3HFlVVdVkBtNBTxfC9gBpPUJm1Fg2AfJ9IO8BEEV2EjxDI0iKLIoA)

Comment: Is there a reason why default Omit implementation doesn't do that? That sounds like a bug since everyone expects it to behave in the way described, and is probably not concerned with its implementation details that prevent it from working this way.